# Text not wrapping in label tag

Tags: html, css

How do you wrap text in a  tag?

I have set the width however text just continues to overflow the element.

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, its whitespace:wrap;

Answer (score 12):

Give this a try

```
 <div style="white-space:wrap">Some long text........</div>
```

Comment: it's invalid property value, the value should be `break-spaces` instead of `wrap`

Answer (score 2):

**To anyone still struggling**, be sure to check and see if you've set a line-height value on the font in question: it could be overriding the word wrap, even if you've done it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Above all, given answers are not working for me.

Bootstrap has all CSS applied for Wrap but still is required, anyone can use

```
style='word-break:break-all;'
```

This works in Label tag and all other tags.

Answer (score 1):

Is the tag floated?
-if so then add this after the text `<div style='clear:both; width:100%; height:1px;'></div>`

Please show us the code so we can see exactly what your doing.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to do anything to get this effect in a basic div, but you can try "word-wrap: break-word" in the style of your element. For example, try resizing a window with:

```html
<div style='word-wrap: break-word'>Here's a div with a ton, a ton, a ton, a ton, a ton, a ton, a ton, a ton, a ton, a ton, a ton, a ton, a ton, a ton, a ton of text.</div>
```

Check out this JS Fiddle to try it out http://jsfiddle.net/zCQFb/ (from Michael's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7166571).