# Making a paragraph text wrap inside a div

Tags: css

I read this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587964/wrap-text-inside-fixed-div-with-css-or-javascript). I have one simple goal.  I just want my text to wrap one time in IE 9.  There are only two lines and I need it to wrap from the first to the second.  This can not be complicated.  I tried adding wrap-text:normal to the supporting div but this did not work.  The layout is simple - bascially I have a div containing an image a link and a paragraph.  I need the paragraph to wrap inside the div.  The text is limited so it will only wrap once.

The image show that when it exceeds the div width it breaks in a way that is strange.

There are alot of SO posts regarding this but they look like a spider web of info.  I'm considering redesigning the mini-feed from the ground up unless someone has a quick fix for this seemingly simple issue.

[image: broken image]

Comment: The pic is helpful, but we need your HTML/CSS for the elements in question.

Comment: ..preferably also in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) format so we're all definitely looking at the same thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

maybe this can help you by a little.. :)

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="50" height="50" style="float:left;" /><div style="float:left; width:200px; max-width:200px; word-wrap:break-word;">Your text here.</div>
```

I hope that can help you..
CMIIW ^_^

Comment: cool...thanks i'm going to rebuild it using this as a starting point

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like `word-wrap: break-word`? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zCQFb/ It doesn't wrap it only one time though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the `paragraph` a set `width`?

If so, make it the `width` of the `div` or a bit smaller and it should work out.

---

I would need to see the code (HTML and CSS) to offer a more detailed answer.

Comment: k, i tried setting the paragraph widhth but this did not work....i am going to do a rebuild and post in that jfiddle thing as time permits.  thanks